# Creating a "Block Function" for jQuery/PHP chat

Tags: php, jquery, chat

I created my own version of this chat.. http://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/ . Everything works fine, people can sign on, send messages and see other people's messages. There is even a list of who is in the room. I also have an ADMIN account that requires a password.

My problem is I can't figure out a good way of creating a "Block Function" or some other way of kicking the user out of the window/chat room so that in case there is a rowdy person in the room, as the ADMIN I can block him or kick him out or something along those lines.

Does anyone have any ideas on an easy way to do this?

PHP file to save names to list..

```
$function = $_POST['function'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$filename = "chatList.txt";

 switch($function) {

     case('writeName'):
        $fo = fopen($filename,'a');
        fwrite($fo, $name."\r\n");
        fclose($fo);
        break;

     case('deleteName'):
        $file = file_get_contents($filename);
        $fo = fopen($filename,'w');
        $str =  str_replace($name."\r\n","",$file,$count);
        fwrite($fo, $str, strlen($str));
        fclose($fo);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count-1; $i++)
        {   
            $fo = fopen($filename,'a');
            fwrite($fo, $name."\r\n");
            fclose($fo);  
        }

        break;

    case('updateList'):
         $fo = fopen($filename,'r');
         if($fo)
         {
            $array = explode('\r\n', fread($fo, filesize($filename)));
         }
         echo json_encode($array);

         break;


}
```

Comment: What exact problem have you encountered?

Comment: I can't figure out a way to create a block for the ADMIN to use. Since the way it works is writing information to a txt file using php it's hard to grab items. There is NO database used in this implementation. That is the problem I am having.

Comment: How do you keep a list of who is in each room?  It seems to me you could use that data structure/file/whatever to also know who is blocked from the room.  Then, when people try to join/post to a room they are blocked from you can reject them.

Comment: Just added the code above to show how I keep a list of who is in the room.

Comment: You should report this feature request to the tutorial site you've got that software from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remove the person from the list and then added an if statement to block them from messaging...

```
if(!$('#online div#usernames:contains('+name+')').length > 0){
                alert('You have been blocked!');
                return; 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Find out what your user's ip is :

```
function getIP() {
 $ip;
 if (getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP")) $ip = getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP"); 
  elseif(getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")) $ip = getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"); 
  elseif(getenv("REMOTE_ADDR")) $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
  else $ip = "UNKNOWN";
 return $ip;
}
```

2) Modify your delete, update and write functions so they also write the ip address
3) Call the delete function with the ip from the user and done !

Comment: I will have to try this... I'll let you know how it goes.